# Multiplication by an element inducing the identity on a quotient

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, complex-multiplication

I am studying the chapter on the associated Grössencharacter of a CM ellipic curve in Silverman's *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* (II.9.) and have a question concerning a specific step in the proof of

**Theorem 9.1.** Let $x \in \mathbf{A}_L^\times$ be an idele of $L$ and let $s = N^L_K(x) \in \mathbf{A}_K^\times$. Then there exists a unique $\alpha = \alpha_{E/L}(x) \in K^\times$ with the following properties:

1. $\alpha\mathcal{O}_K = (s)$,
2. For any fractional ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq K$ and any complex analytic isomorphism $f \colon \mathbb{C}/ \mathfrak{a} \rightarrow E(\mathbb{C})$ one has

\begin{align}
[x,L] \circ f_{|K/\mathfrak{a}} = f \circ \text{mult}_{\alpha s^{-1}}.
\end{align}

My problem lies in the following. When showing uniqueness of such an element $\alpha \in K^{\times}$, one finds that (if $\alpha' \in K^{\times}$ is another element satisfying the properties) multiplication by $\alpha' \alpha^{-1}$ is the identity on $K/\mathfrak{a}$. Then Silverman concludes $\alpha' = \alpha$. How is this done? I only see that $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ have the same image in $K/\mathfrak{a}$ and seem to miss something obvious..

**UPDATE:** I guess I have it now.. The continuous maps $\text{id}$ and multiplication by $\alpha' \alpha^{-1}$ from $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$ to $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$ agree when restricted to the dense subset $K/\mathfrak{a}$. As $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$ is Hausdorff, one can easily show that this implies $\text{id} = \text{mult}_{\alpha'\alpha^{-1}}$. Hence both the elements $1$ and $\alpha'\alpha^{-1}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ give the identity on $\mathbb{C}/\mathfrak{a}$ and therefore are equal.